# What is the projection of a vector x on the subspace M parallel to subspace K

Tags: linear-algebra

So here I have a vector $x = (-1, 0, 2, 0, 0)$
Subspace $M = \text{span}\{f_1=(-1, -1, 1, 0, 0), f_2=(-1, -1, -2, 0, 1, 0), f_3=(-1, 0, 0, 0, 1)\}$

Direct complement $K = \text{span}\{g_1=(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), g_2=(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)\}$

I need the projection of vector $x$ to $M$ parallel to $K$

What I tried is represent vector $x$ as linear combination of vectors from $M$ and $K$
$$x = α_1*f_1 + α_2*f_2 + α_3*f_3 + β_1*g_1 + β_2*g_2$$
So I finally got
$$α_1 = 2, α_2 = -1, α_3 = 0$$
$$β_1 = 1, β_2 = 0$$

Then lastly I used the scalars $α_1$, $α_2$ and $α_3$ and calculated the projection using only vectors from subspace $M, x = 2*f_1 - f_2$ which is $x = (-1, 0, 2, -1, 0)$

Is this the right way?